# Flutter web giving unhandled exception error when trying to run

Tags: linux, google-chrome, terminal, dart

I run an Arch linux system. I have been trying for the past few days to get the flutter for web (hummingbird) to run on my computer. Everytime I try to run it though it gets to starting the web server and gives this error:

```
Unhandled exception:

ProcessException: No such file or directory
  Command: google-chrome --user-data-dir=/tmp/VNKYYL --remote-debugging-port=36287 --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-extensions --disable-popup-blocking --bwsi --no-first-run --no-default-browser-check --disable-default-apps --disable-translate http://127.0.0.1:33379/

0      Chrome.start  (package:webdev/src/serve/chrome.dart:108:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
1      _startChrome  (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:53:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
2      DevWorkflow.start  (package:webdev/src/serve/dev_workflow.dart:178:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
3      DaemonCommand.run  (package:webdev/src/command/daemon_command.dart:86:36)
<asynchronous suspension>
4      CommandRunner.runCommand 
package:args/command_runner.dart:197
<asynchronous suspension>
5      _CommandRunner.runCommand  (package:webdev/src/webdev_command_runner.dart:38:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
6      CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> 
package:args/command_runner.dart:112
7      new Future.sync  (dart:async/future.dart:224:31)
8      CommandRunner.run 
package:args/command_runner.dart:112
9      run  (package:webdev/src/webdev_command_runner.dart:19:56)
```

I followed all the instuctions, and when I do paste the top command into my terminal, it does open up Chrome properly. I even tried reinstalling flutter a few times, and multiple restarts. P

Comment: can you start chrome by command 'google-chrome'?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates, that you have not installed google-chrome properly.
You can either download it and install it, or if you want to use chromium:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/chromium /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Assuming you already have chromium installed.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. He says that pasting the top command opens chrome, so it does sound like `google-chrome` is in his path.

Comment: @bobpaul well it might be in is path of his terminal, but maybe not in the path of android-studio, which seems to act different.
I tried an alias before the symlink and with that alias in `.bashrc` i could open `chromium` with `google-chrome` command, but android-studio still failed.